Relationship between adding more regressors to a linear regression model and the F-statistic of the model
I was thinking about the impact on different parameters in a linear regression model when we add more regressors, but I'm a bit unsure of what happens to the F-statistic.
I know that for $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1 +...+\beta_p x_p$, we have  $({\rm Explained}\ SS/p)/({\rm Residual}\ SS/n-p-1)  \sim F_{p,n-p-1}$, and that ${\rm Residual}\ SS$ will decrease while ${\rm Explained}\ SS$ will increase when we add more regressors to our model. To me, this should mean that the $F$ statistic should increase, but after running some ANOVA tests this doesn't necessarily seem to be the case.
Is my thinking correct in that the $F$ statistic should increase? Or are my preliminary tests correct and the value of the $F$ statistic will be indeterminable?

Pay attention to the fact that as you add regressors, $p$ increases and $n-p-1$ decreases: both cause the ratio $(n-p-1)/p,$ which is a factor of the F statistic, to decrease.

It might be helpful to read my answer to How can adding a 2nd IV make the 1st IV significant?  It discusses the tradeoff between the changing SS and the changing df.

I completely forgot that p will change here as well, thank you for the recommendation!
